# Detect request protocol in NodeJS 7

Tags: node.js, http

I'm using NodeJS 7 and I'm trying to detect the request protocol (HTTP/HTTPS).
How can that be done?
I tried `req.protocol` but apparently it was removed in an earlier version.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @SvenB But how can i get the URL if i don't have the protocol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `req.protocol` is an Express-ism, not something that was ever present in the standard HTTP/HTTPS modules.

For those, you can check `req.connection.encrypted` (if defined then it's HTTPS/TLS).

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure based on your question if you have the request URL, But if you have it,
The [docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/v7.0.0/api/url.html#url_urlobject_protocol) say you can use:

```
 urlObject.protocol
```